# How to execute function within ExpressJS from React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, server, server-side

I have the following function in my `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');

const someFunction = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('ok');
  }, 1000);
};

app.listen(3001, () => someFunction());
```

How can I run this function from a React component? Like if I have a Button component in React:

`<Button onClick={() => express.someFunction(...)}`

Comment: Do you use React on the client/browser? Then you would have to use fetch to call the Express server.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen a bunch of tutorials of how to get data from an express server, but not how to call a function from express. I'm trying to figure out how a setTimeout function called on the client side can persist even when the browser is closed. I'm assuming I can leverage ExpressJS to achieve this.

Comment: It should not be different from getting data from a server. Just instead of getting some data, you call a function.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an express end point that invokes the function. [Learn more about express routing.](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

const someFunction = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('ok');
  }, 1000);
};


// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  someFunction()
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

Then from react you can use [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)) to request that resource like: `fetch(someUrlThatInvokesFunctionGoesHere)`